# rxImport, colClasses and RxTextData

Tags: r, revolution-r, microsoft-r

I am trying to import a `csv` file with Revolution Analytics.

My code is the following:

```
rxImport(inData = mycsv, outFile =myXdf,type="text", colClasses=c('character','character','character','character',
'character','character' ,'character','logical','logical','logical','logical', 'logical','logical','logical', 'logical','logical','logical' ,'numeric','numeric', 'numeric'))
```

I took care to delete `myXdf` before to launch the code and used scan on the first 1000 elements to define the vector `colClasses`.

It gives me the following error:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “RxTextData” object: 'colClasses' must be a named character vector
```

Has somebody already met this error?

Answer (score 2):

To specify the column classes for a text data object, you need to add the column names as a named vector.

Try something like this:

```
# Read first few lines of csv to determine column names
x <- read.csv(mycsv, nrow=5)

# Define desired column classes
colClasses=c('character','character','character','character', 'character','character' ,'character','logical','logical', 'logical','logical', 'logical','logical','logical', 'logical','logical','logical' ,'numeric','numeric', 'numeric')

# Assign csv column names
names(colClasses) <- names(x)

# Define input object
input <- RxTextData(mycsv, colClasses = colClasses)

# Import the data
rxImport(input, myxdf)
```